# Using a combination of readline and another method to split subprocess stderr into tidy logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, subprocess, stderr

I currently have this code:

```
for line in iter(command.stderr.readline, b''):
    line = line.rstrip().decode('utf8')
    logger.debug(line)
```

The command which I'm reading the stderr from is rsync. Sometimes multiple lines are coming out in the logging as single entries, whereas I only want one action to be recorded in each logging message.

For example, the logging is coming out as this:

```
DEBUG: Copying .... gs://xxxxx
DEBUG: Copying .... gs://xxxxx Copying .... gs://xxxxx Copying .... gs://xxxxx Copying .... gs://xxxxx 
DEBUG: Copying gs://xxxxx
```

As the above hopefully demonstrates, it's not successfully splitting each line of the stderr out.

I want for each line to be split out so that every line starts with "Copying". How could I take this readline output from stderr and further filter it so that a new line is produced every time the word "Copying" appears?

Thanks, and let me know if I could make any points clearer.

Comment: What exactly is `command`?

Comment: To get this clear: Do you get multiple lines of output at once, or do you want to create _additional_ linebreaks for each "Copying" operation, even if those are on _the same line_ in the original output?

Comment: @tobias_k command is [location of gsutil cmd, '-m', 'rsync', 'r', 'source', 'destination']

Yes, the latter. Additional linebreaks for each Copying operation, even if those are on the same line in the original output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to split up lines containing multiple copy operations. For this, you could just use a regular expression to `re.split` after any char (to prevent an empty first string) and before`"Copying"`:

```
>>> s = "Copying .... Copying .... Copying .... Copying ...."
>>> re.split("(?<=.)(?=Copying)", s)
['Copying .... ', 'Copying .... ', 'Copying .... ', 'Copying ....']
```

In your loop, this could look e.g. like this (not tested):

```
for line in iter(command.stderr.readline, b''):
    line = line.rstrip().decode('utf8')
    for x in re.split("(?<=.)(?=Copying)", line):
        logger.debug(x)
```

Note: Splitting on empty patterns was added to [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) in Python 3.7

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k.

However, when I run this, I get a ValueError[split() requires a non-empty pattern match.]

Comment: @Mullins Hm, what version of Python are you using? I tested with 3.7. Alternatively, you could just `str.split` by `"Copying"` and then add `"Copying"` back to the beginning of the segments (using the empty match has the advantage that nothing is "lost" in the split).

Comment: Ahhh, I think I know why this code doesn't work.

When I said "Copying ...", it actually has the name of the file being copied over, so it would look like "Copying .... gs://bucketname/file_name".

I imagine this requires a different regex?

Comment: @Mullins No, that should not be the problem. Note how in my example the `"...."` are also part of the split strings although they are not in the pattern. I'd think it's the version of the `re` module.